# Backstage (from Spotify) Templates with Grid controls

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms, backstage

I am using Spotify's Backstage software catalog UX to create products.  My problem arises when using the Backstage Templates engine to create the steps to create this product.

Currently the template renders each parameter as a single page-wide text field on the template form.  However, I am trying to customize the template to permit a grid-like set of text fields.

Is there a way to customize the "template.yaml" file to permit multiple text fields (in a simple grid format) per line?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question properly, but here I present an example that has "steps" to fill in:

```
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: example-repository
  title: Example Repository
  description: An Example
  tags:
    - recommended
    - template
spec:
  owner: group:team
  type: component
  parameters:
    - title: Provide some simple information
      required:
        - component_id
        - owner
      properties:
        component_id:
          title: Name
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          ui:field: EntityNamePicker
        description:
          title: Description
          type: string
          description: Help others understand what this website is for.
        owner:
          title: Owner
          type: string
          description: Owner of the component
          ui:field: OwnerPicker
          ui:options:
            allowedKinds:
              - Group
    - title: Choose a location
      required:
        - repoUrl
      properties:
        repoUrl:
          title: Repository Location
          type: string
          ui:field: RepoUrlPicker
          ui:options:
            requestUserCredentials:
              secretsKey: USER_OAUTH_TOKEN
              additionalScopes:
                github: 
                  - workflow
            allowedHosts:
              - github.com
  steps:
    - id: template
      name: Fetch Skeleton + Template
      action: fetch:template
      input:
        url: ./content
        copyWithoutRender:
          - .github/workflows/*
        values:
          component_id: ${{ parameters.component_id }}
          description: ${{ parameters.description }}
          destination: ${{ parameters.repoUrl | parseRepoUrl }}
          owner: ${{ parameters.owner }}

    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:github
      input:
        allowedHosts: ["github.com"]
        description: This is ${{ parameters.component_id }}
        repoUrl: ${{ parameters.repoUrl }}
        repoVisibility: private
        token: ${{ secrets.USER_OAUTH_TOKEN }}

    - id: register
      name: Register
      action: catalog:register
      input:
        repoContentsUrl: ${{ steps.publish.output.repoContentsUrl }}
        catalogInfoPath: "/catalog-info.yaml"

  output:
    links:
      - title: Repository
        url: ${{ steps.publish.output.remoteUrl }}
      - title: Open in catalog
        icon: catalog
        entityRef: ${{ steps.register.output.entityRef }}
```

Comment: This issue is that this template will render each field (component_id, description, and owner) on single line, with each field spanning the entire length of the screen.  I am hoping to use something that allows multiple fields (that are related) to appear on a single line.